# Wordpress Header and Submenu styling frustration with IE

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, wordpress

I am working on a new theme for a Wordpress site. It is mostly done (few more minor tweaks left), but I am having major problems with the menu at the top in IE. It wont center and the submenu stacks weird on the homepage. On every other page, it centers fine and the submenu stacks right, but is pushed to the right. This is frustrating me because the code and css for the menu on the homepage and every other page is exactly the same

Of course, it works fine in every other browser but IE.

Here is the website: http://www.xylemwsus.com

Here is a github repository for the theme: https://github.com/kilokai/Xy-Microsite-new-theme

All pages call the same header (the copy is just the old header) and footer: header.php and footer.php

Homepage calls page-home.php as its template page. Under "Our Brands" those 6 companies all call _landing-company.php as their templates and calls sidebar.php. The product pages (the links in the sidebar for the company pages) all call _product.php.

Comment: it'll help if you can provide some HTML + CSS and specify exactly which version of IE this is occurring on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE is getting thrown into Quirks mode because you have the following code being output before your Doctype declaration;

```
<span id="homepage-flag" style="display: none"></span>
```

Get rid of that and take it from there.